# Error on using getLong() in BIRT report

Tags: report, birt, maximo

This report has been running fine and all of a sudden is giving the below error message

```
A BIRT exception occurred. See next exception for more information.
TypeError: Cannot find function getLong in object com.ibm.tivoli.maximo.report.script.MXReportDataSetImpl@4188e92b. (/report/data-         sets/script-data-set[@id="1990"]/method[@name="fetch"]#29).
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.script.internal.DtEScriptExecutor.handleJS (DtEScriptExecutor.java:99)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.script.internal.DataSetScriptExecutor.handleJS(DataSetScriptExecutor.java:256)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.script.internal.ScriptDataSetScriptExecutor.handleFetch(ScriptDataSetScriptExecutor.java:143)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.ScriptDataSetRuntime.fetch(ScriptDataSetRuntime.java:103)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedScriptDSQuery$ScriptDSQueryExecutor$CustomDataSet.fetch(PreparedScriptDSQuery.java:260)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.OdiAdapter.fetch(OdiAdapter.java:226)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.RowResultSet.fetch(RowResultSet.java:145)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.RowResultSet.doNext(RowResultSet.java:118)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.RowResultSet.next(RowResultSet.java:96)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.ExpandableRowResultSet.next(ExpandableRowResultSet.java:63)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.SmartCacheHelper.populateData(SmartCacheHelper.java:318)
```

Below is the code which has been written in FETCH method that's causing the error. If I change getLong to getString then it works without any issue. However I would like to understand what could cause the issue since it was working fine before without any issue.

```
commLogDataSet = MXReportDataSetProvider.create(this.getDataSource().getName(), "commLogDataSet");
commLogDataSet.open();
commLogSQL = "select commlog.message, commlog.ownerid 
from commlog where commlog.commlogid = " + workLogDataSet.getDouble("worklogid")
;
commLogDataSet.setQuery(commLogSQL);
if(commLogDataSet.fetch()) {
row["recordkey"] = commLogDataSet.**getLong**("ownerid");
row["description"] = commLogDataSet.getString("message");
}
commLogDataSet.close();
}
```

Comment: You should mention the result of the getString method. And BTW I think your approach is a code smell. Why do you change the DS sql manually instead of using bind variables?